# Retrieve a Relative Path to a Directory from another Directory in NAnt

Tags: nant, relative-path

I have a [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) task create copies of MSBuild files. The copies are located in other directories than their originals.

The source files should remain where they are. Therefore, I'm using NAnt's `<style>` task to run an XSLT on the MSBuild files. It replaces the `<Compile/>` elements with `<Compile><Link/></Compile>` subtrees (attributes omitted for the sake of legibility).

I've encountered the following problem:
In the resulting MSBuild files, the `Include` attribute of the `Compile` elements should receive the relative path to the source file from the new location of the MSBuild files. As the original MSBuild files contain the relative paths to the files, what I am actually looking for is the relative path from the new MSBuild file location to the location of the original MSBuild files.

Workarounds that I know how to use, but which I'd like to avoid:

- custom NAnt task
- using substring to remove the mutual prefix of the directory paths (the NAnt base dir)

Is there any better way; possibly a NAnt function or an ingenious way to use several NAnt functions in conjunction to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't absolute paths work?

Comment: Once I commit the generated MSBuild files to a version control and someone else checks them out from there, the absolute paths will be incorrect on his or her machine.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation? No..I didn't think so

Comment: @danrhul: The alternative solutions that I've found are clearly stated in the question for everyone to read (look for "Workarounds"). I have of course read the documentation, which is how I have found out about the stated workarounds. In fact, the Nant task and function references are constantly opened while I work with Nant, and I frequently browse them to find out how to solve problems.